# Make content take up full page CSS + Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this example http://plnkr.co/edit/xnyrIy1LLZLIBAs6VIOr?p=preview

I am just trying to make the textarea take up the whole height of the panel, and the panel take up the whole page of the page. However, of some reason it overflows. Why is that?

```
    <html>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<style>
  body, html{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  textarea{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    resize: none;
    height: 100% !important;
    width:100%;
  }

  .form-control, .panel, .container {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 10px;
      height: 100%;
  }

</style>

<body>

<div id="c2">
<div id="c1">

<div class="container">
<h1>Hello, hello!</h1>
  <div class="panel">
    This is the panel<br><br>
    <textarea class="form-control">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the margin and padding of the textarea:

```
textarea {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Remove the `height: 100%` of the `.form-control, .panel, .container`. And the textarea will no longer overflow.

But, if you want to keep some padding, then change your html:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">This is the panel</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the textarea problem. But the panel and textarea still takes up more than 100% of the page. (remove the overflow:hidden and you'll see)

Comment: If I remove the height 100% the panel and textarea still overflows the page size. I want the panel and textarea to take up the page with scrolling disabled. Take a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/xnyrIy1LLZLIBAs6VIOr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in style separate **form-control** from **panel** and **container**  to remove 100% size problem

```
.form-control{
height: 110%;
margin:10px;
width: 90%;}
```

Check this out :: http://plnkr.co/edit/f7VLf67inHvhsoerx6t3?p=preview

EDIT:
I thought you need only full size of text area please check this 
http://plnkr.co/edit/x8JlgDgFeuZpz27JWDx6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but in your example the panel and textarea still overflows the page size...